# Does HDAPS wear out a hard-drive?

Tags: hard-drive, thinkpad, accelerometer

I’ve installed hdapsd on my Thinkpad. It is a Linux daemon for hdaps that parks the hard-drive whenever the accelerometer detects a shock. Since installing it, I have noticed that even small movements are enough to park the hard drive.

Having read that hard-drives can park the head only a limited number of times before failing, I am worried that this program is reducing the lifespan of the of the drive.

Is this program wearing out my drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked a Lenovo rep about this once, and they said that the drives they purchase for their laptops are tested to support more parks in its lifetime than a typical hard drive. A run-of-the-mill 5400rpm or 7200rpm consumer 3.5" drive is good for about 5000 - 15000 parks; **Lenovo OEM** hard drives should support significantly more before showing signs of failure.

Now, how many more, I don't know. If it's parking every 5 seconds (do you live on a train?) you might have an issue. It isn't really designed to be *constantly* parking -- you're supposed to use your laptop on a flat surface, only occasionally triggering the active protection when you carry around the laptop while it's on, or accidentally drop it.

Also, be warned: aside from completely voiding your warranty on the laptop, installing a non-Lenovo hard drive into a Lenovo laptop and using HDAPS will probably kill that drive pretty quickly due to the aforementioned "special" drives that Lenovo uses.

If you are noticing that HDAPS activates very frequently and that's just how you use your laptop (in a fighter jet? I have no idea...) then you should really consider replacing your HDD(s) with a(n) SSD(s). Cost and capacity aside, SSDs will all but **eliminate** the fear of damage through drops, inertia, etc. -- you'd have to physically crack the drive to break an SSD from physical trauma, and anything that strong would probably also destroy the case/keyboard/panel also.

Comment: Thanks, and no, it's not every five seconds, it's just that even a bump triggers it, or when I (even gently) put it from my lap on my table. And yeah, SSD would be nice, but I can't quite afford it right now, though I'm definitely looking into it.

Comment: On Windows at least, you can modify the sensitivity of the APS. Google around to see if you can do the same on Linux.